# Isn't thin font type not working for the UIPicker?

Tags: swift

I wanted use below font type for the `UIPicker` component:

```
Helvetica Neue Thin
```

I wrote below code for above font property:

```
public func pickerView(_ pickerView: UIPickerView, viewForRow row: Int, forComponent component: Int, reusing view: UIView?) -> UIView {
    let label = view as? UILabel ?? UILabel()
    label.font = UIFont(name: "Helvetica Neue Thin", size: 20)
    label.textColor = .darkGray
    label.textAlignment = .center
    label.text = myPageList[row]
    return label
}
```

Problem is `Thin` type(font property) does not work.
It works when I try `Helvetica Neue` font type without `Thin` property. Can we add `UIFont.Weight` property into above scope?

I have added below code, but it does not show Helvetica Neue font type after using it.

```
label.font = UIFont.systemFont(ofSize: 20, weight: UIFont.Weight.thin)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We can print all the available fonts for Helvetica Neue family like this:

```
let fontNames = UIFont.fontNames(forFamilyName: "Helvetica Neue")
print(fontNames)
```

Note that font name doesn't have spaces in between words.

> ["HelveticaNeue-UltraLightItalic", "HelveticaNeue-Medium",
>   "HelveticaNeue-MediumItalic", "HelveticaNeue-UltraLight",
>   "HelveticaNeue-Italic", "HelveticaNeue-Light",
>   "HelveticaNeue-ThinItalic", "HelveticaNeue-LightItalic",
>   "HelveticaNeue-Bold", "HelveticaNeue-Thin",
>   "HelveticaNeue-CondensedBlack", "HelveticaNeue",
>   "HelveticaNeue-CondensedBold", "HelveticaNeue-BoldItalic"]

So you need to instantiate your font like this:

```
UIFont(name: "HelveticaNeue-Thin", size: 20.0)
```